# New column based on slicer selection

Tags: dax

please help to get the following result in power bi,

Suppose i have two tables with a common column as below:

T1=

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

And T2=

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | cell 2 |
| B | cell 4 |
| C | cell 6 |

In the filter visualization, added the Column 1 of the table T1. I want to add new column to table T2 whose value will be 1 if the column 1 value is selected in filter and else 0. For example, if i select B, C if filter, then my result table will be as follows:

T2=

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | cell 2 | 0 |
| B | cell 4 | 1 |
| C | cell 6 | 1 |

Note that there is no relation between T1 and T2

Tried to add new column by IF function, but did not work

Comment: Calculated Columns will not change based on Slicer/Filter selection. You would need a Measure instead.

Comment: @JosWoolley what will be the dax function to get this column in measure?

Answer (score 0):

This measure:

```
=
VAR SelectedT1Col1Values =
    VALUES( T1[Column 1] )
RETURN
    IF( COUNTROWS( FILTER( T2, T2[Column 1] IN SelectedT1Col1Values ) ), 1, 0 )
```

which can then be added to the visual alongside *Column 1* and *Column 2* from *T2*.